# Pandas: how to read a bitstring into separate columns when no delimiter is present?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, memory

I am trying to read some files into a Pandas dataframe they look something like this:

```
287212,xxxanxxxxx  
5466029,xxxxxxxxxx  
324561,nnnnxnnnna  
687811,xxxxxxxxxn  
67454,nnnaxnnnnn
```

or like this:

```
287226,0010100000  
5466089,1110100000  
324561,0010101000  
687811,0000000000  
67404,0010000000
```

What I want is to use the first multi-digit number as the index column and for the values after the ',' separator I want to split into one column per character.
for example like this:

```
index   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
287216  x x x a n x x x x x  
5466029 x x x x x x x x x x  
324561  n n n n x n n n n a  
687811  x x x x x x x x x n  
67404   n n n a x n n n n n
```

at the moment I have managed to do this like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=',',header=None).set_index(0)  
df = pd.DataFrame(df[1].apply(list).tolist()).set_index(df.index)
```

the problem with this is that the first line of code reads the second column as dtype=object. and then when I split this into a list using the second line f code, each character or value is still as dtype=object and this is consuming a lot of memory. and my script keeps crashing because of memory errors.

is a more direct way to read the csv file and specify the dtypes?

can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: What dtype would you expect in your first dataframe with the `xxxan ..`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry you are right, the first dataframe would remain as **dtype=object.** the second dataframe containing 0's and 1's is the major problem as these are much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the strings into strings of length 1 with NumPy:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.astype("bytes").view("S1"), index=df.index)
```

Or 8-bit integers:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.astype("bytes").view(np.uint8), index=df.index)
```